# How can I send DropDownList's SelectedValue to the Controller from View with BeginForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I send DropDownList's SelectedValue to the Controller from View with BeginForm?

Here's my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new {  newvalue=ddl.SelectedValue}))
{

@Html.DropDownList("categories", 
     (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["categories"], 
      new { onchange = "this.form.submit()", id = "ddl" })
```

Comment: Whats wrong with just using a submit button? Note `new {  newvalue=ddl.SelectedValue}` makes no sense. When you post back the value of `categories` will be the selection value of the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `ViewData` or `ViewBag` in place of your model. It's sloppy, prone to error and just an unorganized way of giving your view data.

```
{ newvalue = ddl.SelectedValue }
```

is going to do nothing for you when placed on the form itself. You need to understand that everything you're writing is evaluated on the server before being sent down the client. So if `newvalue` resolves to `1` it will continue to stay 1 forever unless you have javascript that changes it on the clientside (which you're not doing and you shouldn't be doing).

First you need a model:

```
public class CategoryModel()
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class CategoryController()
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new CategoryModel();
        model.CategoriesList = new List<SelectListItem>{...};
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult SaveCategory(CategoryModel model)
    {
        model.SelectedCategoryId
        ...
    }
}
```

View

```
@model CategoryModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveCategory","Category"))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.SelectedCategoryId, Model.CategoriesList)
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

What's happening here is `SelectList` is being populated from the `IEnumerable` and its form name is `SelectedCategoryId`, that's what is posed back to the server.

I'm not sure where your knowledge of http and html ends, but you should not be using any framework until you understand how http and html work and then what these helpers such as `begin form and Html.DropDownList` are actually doing for you. Understand how the screw works before you try to use the screw driver.